# Similar Query different execution plan and performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

This is the script I use to generate 10M rows on Clients table from 200 different cities. (It took 11 minutes on a desktop PC)

*Important note at the end

```
    -- Crear la tabla Clientes
CREATE TABLE Clientes (
    id_cliente BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    id_ciudad INT,
    nombre NVARCHAR(100),
    email NVARCHAR(320),
    ciudad nvarchar(100)
);


-- Crear la tabla Clientes_Ciudad
CREATE TABLE Clientes_Ciudad (
    id_ciudad INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    ciudad NVARCHAR(100) UNIQUE
);
go 

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[PopulateData]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Crear la tabla de números con 10 millones de registros
    WITH
    L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c 
            FROM (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),
                        (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS D(c)),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L4)
    SELECT TOP 10000000 n INTO #Numbers FROM Nums;

    -- Inserción de ciudades
    INSERT INTO Clientes_Ciudad (ciudad)
    SELECT N'ciudad_' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(n AS NVARCHAR(5)), 5)
    FROM #Numbers
    WHERE n <= 10000;

    -- Calcular la cantidad de clientes por ciudad
    DECLARE @current_city_id INT = 1;
    DECLARE @city_increment INT = 1;
    DECLARE @clients_in_city INT = 1000;

    CREATE TABLE #CityClients (city_id INT PRIMARY KEY, client_start INT, client_end INT);

    WHILE @current_city_id <= 10000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #CityClients (city_id, client_start, client_end)
        VALUES (@current_city_id, @clients_in_city * (@current_city_id - 1) + 1, @clients_in_city * @current_city_id);

        SET @current_city_id = @current_city_id + 1;
        SET @clients_in_city = @clients_in_city + 500 * @city_increment;
        SET @city_increment = @city_increment + 1;
    END

    -- Inserción de clientes
    INSERT INTO clientes (id_ciudad, nombre, email,ciudad)
    SELECT
        CC.city_id,
        N'cliente_' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(N.n AS NVARCHAR(7)), 7),
        N'email_' + CAST(NEWID() AS NVARCHAR(36)) + N'@example.com',
        N'ciudad_' + RIGHT('00000' + CAST(n AS NVARCHAR(5)), 5)
    FROM #Numbers AS N
    INNER JOIN #CityClients AS CC
        ON N.n BETWEEN CC.client_start AND CC.client_end;

    -- Crear índices
    CREATE INDEX idx_clientes_id_ciudad ON clientes (id_ciudad);
    CREATE INDEX idx_clientes_ciudad_nombre_email ON clientes (id_ciudad) INCLUDE (nombre, email);
    CREATE INDEX idx_clientes_ciudad ON Clientes


        -- Eliminar las tablas temporales
    DROP TABLE #Numbers;
    DROP TABLE #CityClients;
END
GO

-- Ejecuta el stored procedure para poblar las tablas
EXEC [dbo].[PopulateData]
GO
delete Clientes_Ciudad where id_ciudad>10000
go
```

I did some sanitization but it is almost the same result.

**The question** is why these two queries perform differently. Why does the second execution plan use Nested Loop (Inner Join) and how to avoid it?

```
    declare @ciudad_id int;
SELECT @ciudad_id= id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00199';

SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email 
FROM clientes
WHERE id_ciudad = @ciudad_id;

SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email
FROM clientes   
WHERE  id_ciudad =(SELECT id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00199');
```

This is the execution plan I got. If I change `ciudad = N'Ciudad_00199'` for a different one in one of the queries, the result is the same.

[image: Execution plan]

### NOTE

From the scratch.

I was proving to a friend these two queries perform slightly differently in favor of the former, and it did.

```
SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email 
FROM clientes
WHERE id_ciudad = 18;
  

SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email
FROM clientes a INNER JOIN Clientes_Ciudad b ON a.id_ciudad = b.id_ciudad
WHERE b.ciudad = N'Ciudad_00018';
```

But, when I compare this, both perform the same. Surprisingly for me

```
SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email
FROM clientes   
WHERE  id_ciudad =(SELECT id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00017');


SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email
FROM clientes a INNER JOIN Clientes_Ciudad b ON a.id_ciudad = b.id_ciudad
WHERE b.ciudad = N'Ciudad_00018';
```

So I craft the script for getting the variable first and got the results and the performance I wanted and came here to help me understand what was going on and how to do it in a single query and not the script(just to learn if it is possible, no special need)

```
declare @ciudad_id int;
SELECT @ciudad_id= id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00015';

SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email 
FROM clientes
WHERE id_ciudad = @ciudad_id;
  

SELECT id_cliente, nombre, email
FROM clientes   
WHERE  id_ciudad =(SELECT id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00017');
```

The engine is more intelligent than I am, and I know that after `WHERE  id_ciudad =` you can accept only a scalar value (or null), so why it is using a nested loop, and how can I force the other way?

### NOTE2

Link to query plan
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJXcbeG-3

Comment: Those percentages are meaningless. As for the query plan, why would you not expect a different plan? The latter has to perform a join between the 2 tables, the former uses a scalar value; the queries aren't similar.

Comment: @ThomA Using `(SELECT top 1 id_ciudad FROM Clientes_Ciudad WHERE ciudad = N'Ciudad_00199');` is an scalar value as well, but again it considers it as a JOIN.

Comment: No, that's not a scalar value, that's a subquery that *returns* a dataset containing a single column and a single arbitrary row. `@ciudad_id` doesn't cause the data engine to invoke the query you use to assign it, the variable has already been assigned. *If* the value of `id_ciudad` (the column not the variable) changed between the assignment and the `SELECT` the value of `@id_ciudad` (the variable) won't change.

Comment: Please paste in links to the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com, rather than unreadable screenshots.

Comment: Is `Clientes_Ciudad.ciudad` unique, or supposed to be so? If so you should create a unique covering index on it.

Comment: @Charlieface it is unique, is the FK, please see my notes

Comment: @ThomA yes, ok, I know, you are right, but we are missing the point, please see my note, I just added one

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ciudad ON Clientes_Ciudad (ciudad) INCLUDE (id_ciudad)` and then compare the query plans. Like I said, we need to see the full query plans, please share links as mentioned.

Comment: The fact that the query is doing a *scan*, @German , means that the data engine *isn't* aware that it's unique.

Comment: Also, the defintion for your index `idx_clientes_ciudad` is incomplete: `CREATE INDEX idx_clientes_ciudad ON Clientes` There are no columns defined in it.

Comment: Also, if I comment that line out, you get the error *"Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int."* Can you provide some working SQL for us to use please?

Comment: @Charlieface the site is down, unfortunately. I got slightly different QP for the first query before and after the Unique Index, but the same performance. No change in the second query, the one I would like to improve

Comment: The correct link for [paste the plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Great, plan added

Comment: @ThomA thanks for the link. I created a scalar function but got the same results `WHERE  id_ciudad =  dbo.ObtenerIdCiudad(N'Ciudad_00117');`

Comment: @Charlieface link to query plan added

Comment: Appreciate this question has been answered now but to make these questions easier to answer in future, please be aware that the second plan in the screenshot is different to the second plan in the paste the plan output. Also, your setup code returns various errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is nothing wrong with the join query.** It's a perfectly decent plan, and is as efficient as the two separate queries.

SQL Server has recognized that the inner subquery can be transformed into a join. It is normally very good at such things.

In the first version, you did not have a unique index/constraint on `ciudad`, so to use a join correctly it had to ensure that a maximum of one row was returned. That was what the *Assert* was doing.

In the second version, the compiler has correctly recognized that the subquery is guaranteed to return exactly one row (or none) so it has transformed into a join.

**The *Nested Loops* is not a problem,** as the outer side is only a single row anyway. The result of that row is fed into the *Nested Loops* as an outer reference, so it is doing a *Seek* on the second table, rather than scanning the whole thing (ie this is not a *Naive Nested Loops*). This query is almost exactly the same in logical terms as doing the two halves separately.

Comment: Those percentage numbers misleading me. Query times in milliseconds are equivalent in any test I ran.

Comment: Indeed, percentage is a meaningless relative estimate of the total query cost (which is itself only a rough guideline)